# How to generate all possible (10x10) matrices containing only 0s and 1s, along with other restrictions, for a Graph Theory application

Tags: matlab, matrix, while-loop, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

***EDIT TO REQUIREMENT 6 AND NEW REQUIREMENT ADDED***
6) Exactly 4 columns/rows must have degree 3.
7) No two vertices of degree 3 are adjacent to each other.

My goal:
To generate and save all matrices that meet specific requirements. Then compare each matrix to additional matrices that have been manually entered previously to check for specific similarities. I can add more detail if somebody thinks it would be helpful. I believe I have the comparison aspect of the code sorted out already, so I am waiting on the matrix generation portion. I need to do this for multiple sizes but I will focus this question on the 10x10 case.

Specific requirements:
1) Must be a 10x10 matrix (representing a graph on 10 vertices).
2) Must be symmetric (representing an adjacency matrix).
3) Have a diagonal of 0s (no loops).
4) Only 1s and 0s (simple graph).
5) The entire matrix must have exactly 48 1s (the graph has 24 edges).
6) Each column/row must have either 3 or 6 1s (each node as degree 3 or 6).

Application:
   I am investigating a conjecture and believe I have come up with a possible solution which could break down the conjecture into smaller pieces and possibly prove some aspects. I want to use brute force to show if my idea works for a small specific case. Also having a base code in place could allow for future modifications to test other possible cases or ideas.
Ideas and thought process:

- I used the edges of a graph to manually input my comparison set. For example:

`G9=graph([1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6 3 3 9 2 2 2 7 7 8],[2 3 4 3 4 4 5 6 7 6 7 7 3 9 10 9 10 10 7 8 9 8 9 9]);`

- I think this is the only graph, up to isomorphism, which meets the previously listed requirements.
- My original thought was to create the possible matrices that satisfy the given conditions then compare them to my comparison set. I still think this is the best approach.
- I foolishly attempted to generate random matrices, completely overlooking the massive number of possibilities. Using a while loop, I first generated a random matrix that satisfied the first four requirements. Then in separate nested for statements I checked for requirement 5 using numedes() and requirement 6 using all(mod(degree())). That was a bad approach for several fairly obvious reasons, but I learned a lot through the process and it led me to the code that should do my final comparisons.
- This is the first time I have used Matlab so I am learning as I go. I have been working on this one code for nearly 2 weeks and do not know if what I have come up with is "good", but I am proud of what I have been able to do by myself. I have reached the point where I feel like I need some outside advice. I am open to any suggestions and any level of help. A reference to a source, a function suggestion, another approach, or a complete solution with a "plug and play" code would be appreciated. I do not shy away from putting forth the effort to achieve my goals. 
  I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician and I'm not sure what you mean by requirement 2, but maybe it could be exploited to reduce the problem...

Comment: I'm still working on bringing down the computation time, but in the mean time, I think I've got at least **one** solution that satisfies your constraints and is not isomorphic to yours: `([1 1 1 2 2 5 3 5 6 3 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 6 7 8 9],[2 3 4 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0])`.

Comment: @beaker Your example does satisfy my constraints, unfortunately, I have realized my constraints are not enough to generate only the matrices which are sufficient for the conjecture I am working on. I will be updating my question tonight to notate my findings. I need the generated graphs to be decomposable into four 4-complete graphs. I am not sure how I could code that constraint. I think this specific case must have exactly 4 nodes of degree 3 and those 4 nodes cannot be adjacent to each other. If that is the case, I should be able to code that. I would need to prove that is true though.

Comment: If you have 24 edges, and all nodes are of degree 3 or 6, the only valid configuration is to have 4 nodes of degree 3 and 6 nodes of degree 6. (This was one of the ways I sped up my function.) You *could* have nodes within a K_4 subgraph from the degree-3 nodes, however. Just not all of them, unless you're allowed to have disconnected subgraphs.

Comment: Which just made me realize that I didn't restrict my function to generate only connected graphs. :)

Comment: @beaker That is one of the reasons I am using the case with 10 vertices first. It requires the graph to be connected and it should be easy to formally prove the degree requirements. Later I will need to consider graphs with order 11, 12, and 13 which allow for more possibilities, but that is for another day.

Comment: @beaker What method did you use to generate your solution? Are you generating random matrices or are you going through every possible matrix? I am currently using a while loop to generate a random matrix that satisfies the number of edges and node degrees, then checking for several other constraints including an isomorphic relation with a known edge set I have found. I do not like basing my results on randomly generated matrices, so I would be interested if you had a better approach.

Comment: I was basically using brute force/backtracking to generate only valid graphs with a couple of optimizations. First, we know that we need 4 nodes with degree 3 and 6 nodes with degree 4 for the 10 node case. I fixed the degree for nodes 1-4 at 3 and for nodes 5-10 at 4, since any graph with a different distribution would be isomorphic to one of mine. Second, and I think similarly to [@peterfranciscook's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378563/1377097) below, after selecting the combination for row/column `p`, the problem would be reduced to a smaller graph of `n-p` nodes.

Comment: For a graph of 10 nodes, finding all of the solutions took me about 15 minutes using Octave (MATLAB would probably be a bit faster). Unfortunately, scaling the problem to 11 nodes would increase the time by `11C4`, or about 300x.

Comment: Sorry, degree 3 and degree 6. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want to brute force it, you've got 3773655750150 possible configurations to test for 3-or-6-connectedness. I think you'll probably need more powerful math (Polya Enumeration Theorem? or some other combinatoric theorem I probably forgot) to solve this one.

edit: This recursive solution is much more constrained and is likely to finish in the next century.

```
E = containers.Map('KeyType', 'int32', 'ValueType', 'any');
for k = 0:9
    E(k) = [];
end

foo(E, 3, 0);
foo(E, 6, 0);

function E = foo(E, D, n)
    % E : graph edges (map)
    % D : degree (3 or 6)
    % n : current node

    if (n == 9)
        e_degree = cellfun(@length,E.values);
        if all(e_degree) && all(~mod(e_degree,3))
            print_E(E)
        end
        return
    end

    e = E(n); % existing edges
    m = setdiff((n+1:9), e); % candidate new edges
    K = D - length(e);
    % if too many edges, return early
    if (K < 0)
        return
    end
    C = combnk(m, K);

    N = size(C, 1);
    for k = 1:N


        c = C(k,:);
        E(n) = unique([e, c]);

        for kv = 1:K
            v = c(kv);
            E(v) = unique([E(v), n]);
        end

        % down the rabbit hole
        E = foo(E, D, n + 1);

        for D = 3:3:6
            E = foo(E, D, n + 1);
        end

        % remove edges added in this loop
        E(n) = setdiff(E(n), c);
        for kv = 1:K
            v = c(kv);
            E(v) = setdiff(E(v), n);
        end

    end

end

function print_E(E)
    for k = 0:9
        fprintf('%i: ',k);
        fprintf('%i ', E(k));
        fprintf('\n');
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

Comment: 3773655750150 possible configurations is (nC2)Cm. That considers all labeled connected graphs on n vertices and m edges. My constraints greatly decrease the number of possibilities. Since each matrix is symmetric and simple, I only need to consider a triangle minus the diagonal. The degree constraint further reduces the possibilities. Also, I can limit my graphs to isomorphic classes which reduces the possibilities because I can focus on unlabled graphs. The number is still large, but more realistic. I will edit my question to address additional information.

Comment: @James I had written 3773655750150 as 45C24 assuming the combinatorics only on the upper triangular matrix. I thought about it last night and came up with this recursive solution which ought to run a lot quicker, but will probably return rotations/translations/symmetric graphcs. Worst case `(9C3 + 9C6) * (8C3 + 8C6) * (7C3 + 7C6) * (6C3 + 1) * (5C3) * (4C3)` evaluations, which is an improvement over the factorial algorithm I had up before.

Comment: I have been playing around with this and I cannot seem to improve it any. It prints every edge set where every vertex has degree mod 3 even if it does not have exactly 24 edges. It also prints the same edge set numerous times. How can I limit the edge sets to exactly 24 edges and can I check for an isomorphism before printing/storing the edge set? I have a valid edge set listed above and it would help if I could use isisomorphic() before the code labels the new edge set as valid.

Comment: @James I’ll play around with it some more. I got a slightly faster approach after I posted this last update. Interesting problem

Comment: It really is. This is actually just one case of the problem for the value 4. I have generalized the problem and know exactly how many vertices are possible, edges, the exact number of columns with specific sums, how many separating vertices are in the graph, along with several other properties for every value greater than 3. Applying that information in a working code is turning out to be as hard as generalizing the problem.